# Counting multiple associated entries of same model with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables, `transaction` and `account`. A `transaction` has at least one and optional a second associated `account` trough two diffrent foreign keys. **Using Sequelize (6.32.0), how do I count all `transaction`s associated to `account` trough the first (id_account) or second (id_account_destination) foreign key?**

sql query to achieve:

```
SELECT `account`.`id`, `account`.`name`, COUNT(`transactions`.`id`) AS `transaction_count`
    FROM  `accounts` AS `account`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `transactions` AS `transactions`
    ON `account`.`id` = `transactions`.`id_account`
    OR `account`.`id` = `transactions`.`id_account_destination`
    GROUP BY `transactions`.`id_account`;
```

model definitions:

```
// account
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define("account", {
        id: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }
    });
};

// transaction
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define("transaction", {
        id: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4
        },
        id_account: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        id_account_destination: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: true
        },
        amount: {
            type: DataTypes.DOUBLE
        }
    });
};
```

model relations:

```
db.transaction.belongsTo(db.accounts, { foreignKey: 'id_account', as: 'account' });
db.transaction.belongsTo(db.accounts, { foreignKey: 'id_account_destination', as: 'account_destination' });
```

working solution for counting trough one association:
*(still wondering why he is choosing the second association trough id_account_destination)*

```
    db.accounts.findAll({
        subQuery: false,
        attributes: {
            include: [[db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.sequelize.col('transactions.id')), 'transaction_count']],
        },
        include: [
            { model: db.transaction, attributes: [] }
        ],
        group: ['transactions.id_account']
    })
```

attempt with error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTableName')"

```
    db.accounts.findAll({
        subQuery: false,
        attributes: {
            include: [[db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.sequelize.col('transactions.id')), 'transaction_count']],
        },
        include: [
            { model: db.transaction, attributes: [], through: 'account_destination' }
            { model: db.transaction, attributes: [], through: 'account' }
        ],
        group: ['transactions.id_account']
    })
```